# Размер фото пропорционален разрешению экрана

Tags: android

Пытаюсь реализовать следующее:
Есть фото. Нужно, чтобы оно сильно не растягивалось (фото человека) в зависимости от разрешения экрана. Ширина - всегда wrap_content, а, вот, как с  высотой поступить? 
Пробовал менять значение в values - dimens в зависимости от плотности экрана (кажется, так это называется): для mdpi - свои значения, для hdpi - свои и т.д. Но тут есть подвох: при одинаковой плотности экрана есть разное его разрешение. Например,  mdpi существует как для экранов с разрешением 768x1280, так и 320x480. И везде изображение выглядит по-разному. Как быть в такой ситуации? Что можно сделать, чтобы изображение выглядело хотя бы примерно одинаково?

Comment: с длинной? Хотели сказать с высотой?

Comment: а если высота wrap_content тоже?

Comment: @s_klepcha , да, Вы правы. Сейчас исправлю )

Comment: Не ясна суть вопроса. Что мешает сделать высоту `wrap_content`?  Тогда пропорции вообще не будут искажаться. Или задать высоту константой в dp. Тогда на всех девайсах размер будет одинаковый.

Comment: @anber , фото по высоте слишком высокое. Оно еще, к тому же, вложено в ScroolView.

Comment: А задавая в dp, на экранах с xxxhdpi выглядит ооооочень маленьким по высоте

Comment: @user186295 Задавая в dp физический размер будет одинаковый для всех денсити, если без dimens.

Comment: @anber , тогда очень странно, поскольку я изначально указывал все размеры чисто в dp безо всяких dimens. И изображение на экранах с большим разрешением и на экранах с маленьким выглядело действительно по-разному.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте высоту и ширину match_parent, и задайте параметр scaleType = "centrInside"

Если не надо match_parent, то с таким scaleType можете задать любые размеры в dp, должно отобразиться без искажений

Comment: center и centerInside синонимичны? Второго просто нет

Comment: @user186295 они разные http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1846580&seqNum=2

Comment: должно быть, у ImageView android:scaleType="centerInside"